# asp.net mvc razor - "reexecute" action in ajax completed call

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I use `@Ajax.BeginForm` to submit form (which lies in modal dialog and adds note to database), on submit that modial dialog is closed without page reloading.  Inside same view I have call to `@Html.Action("GetNotes", "Notes", ..params)` which renders notes panel.

I'd like to "re-execute" this action when `OnAjaxCompleted` is called - is it possible (or is there any better method to achieve that) ?

Comment: You can invoke an action with an AJAX call.  Is there a way to invoke another AJAX call in `OnAjaxCompleted`?  (If you were doing this with jQuery, for example, the `.done()` handler would simply have another call to `$.ajax()` to invoke the `GetNotes` action.)  Of course, then I imagine you'd want to *do something* with the HTML response of that action?  Such as set it to some page element?  (Again, in jQuery you'd probably just call `.load()` on that element to make the AJAX call in the first place.)

Comment: @David thanks for response - calling action is not a problem, problem is that this action returns PartialView - how could I substitute old partial view with new one?

Comment: uhm that was pretty simple - just call $.ajax() {  url = '@Url.Action(. . )', success: function(result) { $('partialViewDiv').html(result) }. I should investigate more next time before I ask question.